# optimization without a set function

Tags: optimization

I currently have a dataset that includes two columns that are of interest to me: price and points. Each item has both a price and a point number attached to it. I am trying to optimize the number of points (point range is from 80-100, price range is from 4-3300) that it is possible to purchase given a certain budget. The problem I'm facing, though, is that the optimization has to be a combination of three products. So, for example, the question would be what is the highest possible total point number given a budget of 20 (i.e. the price of the three items cannot exceed 20).

I've looked at a variety of optimization packages, from Ipsolve to optim, but haven't been able to find anything that works without requiring a function.

Any recommendations on what kind of function to use or which package would best apply?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 0):

This can be modeled as a simple MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) model:

```
max sum(i, points(i)*x(i))         (maximize points)
sum(i, price(i)*x(i)) <= Budget    (stay within budget)
sum(i, x(i)) = n                   (exactly n=3 picks)
x(i) ∈ {0,1}                       (x are binary variables)
```